# Handling race condition in model.save()

Tags: python, database, django, django-models, race-condition

How should one handle a possible race condition in a model's `save()` method?

For example, the following example implements a model with an ordered list of related items. When creating a new Item the current list size is used as its position.

From what I can tell, this can go wrong if multiple Items are created concurrently.

```
class OrderedList(models.Model):
    # ....
    @property
    def item_count(self):
        return self.item_set.count()

class Item(models.Model):
    # ...
    name   = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    parent = models.ForeignKey(OrderedList)
    position = models.IntegerField()
    class Meta:
        unique_together = (('parent','position'), ('parent', 'name'))

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.id:
            # use item count as next position number
            self.position = parent.item_count
        super(Item, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

I've come across [@transactions](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/transactions/#controlling-transaction-management-in-views)`.commit_on_success()` but that seems to apply only to views. Even if it did apply to model methods, I still wouldn't know how to properly handle a failed transaction.

I am currenly handling it like so, but it feels more like a hack than a solution

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    while not self.id:
        try:
            self.position = self.parent.item_count
            super(Item, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
        except IntegrityError:
            # chill out, then try again
            time.sleep(0.5)
```

Any suggestions?

### Update:

Another problem with the above solution is that the `while` loop will never end if `IntegrityError` is caused by a `name` conflict (or any other unique field for that matter).

For the record, here's what I have so far which seems to do what I need:

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):   
    # for object update, do the usual save     
    if self.id: 
        super(Step, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
        return

    # for object creation, assign a unique position
    while not self.id:
        try:
            self.position = self.parent.item_count
            super(Step, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
        except IntegrityError:
            try:
                rival = self.parent.item_set.get(position=self.position)
            except ObjectDoesNotExist: # not a conflict on "position"
                raise IntegrityError
            else:
                sleep(random.uniform(0.5, 1)) # chill out, then try again
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It may *feel* like a hack to you, but to me it looks like a legitimate, reasonable implementation of the "optimistic concurrency" approach -- try doing whatever, detect conflicts  caused by race conditions, if one occurs, retry a bit later.  Some databases systematically uses that instead of locking, and it can lead to much better performance except under systems under a *lot* of write-load (which are quite rare in real life).

I like it a lot because I see it as a general case of the Hopper Principle: "it's easy to ask forgiveness than permission", which applies widely in programming (especially but not exclusively in Python -- the language Hopper is usually credited for is, after all, Cobol;-).

One improvement I'd recommend is to wait a *random* amount of time -- avoid a "meta-race condition" where two processes try at the same time, both find conflicts, and both retry *again* at the same time, leading to "starvation".  `time.sleep(random.uniform(0.1, 0.6))` or the like should suffice.

A more refined improvement is to lengthen the expected wait if more conflicts are met -- this is what is known as "exponential backoff" in TCP/IP (you wouldn't have to lengthen things exponentially, i.e. by a constant multiplier > 1 each time, of course, but that approach has nice mathematical properties).  It's only warranted to limit problems for *very* write-loaded systems (where multiple conflicts during attempted writes happen quite often) and it may likely not be worth it in your specific case.

Comment: Thanks Alex. Good to know I'm not barking up the wrong tree on this one.

Answer (score 0):

Add optional FOR UPDATE clause to QuerySets  http://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/2705

Answer (score 0):

I use Shawn Chin's solution and it proves very useful. The only change I did was to replace the

```
self.position = self.parent.item_count
```

with

```
self.position = self.parent.latest('position').position
```

just to make sure I am dealing with the latest position number (which in my case might not be item_count because of some reserved unused positions)